# Can't post @ to API via curl PHP

Tags: php, api, codeigniter, post, curl

I have something very strange going on here. I am building a API using CodeIgniter that uses data posted to it via CURL.

A WordPress site is posting information to the CodeIgniter API, and all is working, apart from when a password input field posts a string containing an @.

I straight away put this down to XSS protection, but this is disabled. I get no CURL errors, and the data isn't received by the CodeIgniter method (but is when there's no @).

I've tried everything, googled it to no avail, tried using htmlentities(), no luck whatsoever.

I've tried printing $_POST['fieldname'] before the data gets passed to CURL and it prints the string back (even when containing '@'), and on the codeIgniter side to debug, I've tried getting a method to return the sent data which it does, unless the sent data contains @. At my whits end, tried using my REST client to test codeIgniter API and that strangely works fine when sending strings with @, so I'm guessing its something wrong with the CURL command?

Thanks in advance.
Ste

-- EDIT: Code --

```
/* WORDPRESS SITE */
// ....


// When $_POST['pass'] doesn't contain '@' it passes data fine,
// print $_POST['pass'] works too even with an '@'... 
// ...also tried htmlentities($_POST['pass']) with no luck
$data_to_post = array('pass' => $_POST['pass'], 'user' => $_POST['user']);

$result = do_api_call('return_posted_values', $data_to_post);

// ....

function do_api_call($method, $request = array()) {

    $ch = curl_init(API_URL.$method);

    // Add the api key to the request
    $request['api_key'] = API_KEY;

    foreach ($request as $key => $value) {

        // Serialize any arrays
        if (is_array($value)) $request[$key] = serialize($value);
    }

    // Set the curl
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $request);     
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);


    $result = curl_exec($ch);
    $status = curl_getinfo($ch);

    curl_close($ch);

    //print $result;
    $result = json_decode($result);
    return $result;
}

/* CODEIGNITER SIDE */

/* THIS METHOD IS IN API CLASS */
public function return_posted_values() {

    // Return the posted data as string works fine when the data has no @
    $return $this->input->post('user').' - '.$this->input->post('pass');
    $this->response($return);

}
```

Comment: Post your code, without seeing it, we can't tell you what you are doing wrong or aren't doing...

Answer (score 0):

Replace @ with %40 inside your password. or use **urlencode()** function over the password to escape these characters.